# Where should a virtual environment folder be placed relative to the main project directory?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, virtual-environment, nodeenv

I understand that the idea behind a virtual environment is to give your project's dependencies a local installation as opposed to a global one. I followed the steps to successfuly create and activate a virtual environment for node using [`nodeenv`](https://github.com/ekalinin/nodeenv). However, I'm curious as to where to place this folder relative to my project folder. For this example, I am using a [Github repo](https://github.com/seanpmaxwell/express-generator-typescript). Does the `env` folder go *inside* my project folder? Or should I create the `env` folder and then install the Github repo inside of it?

**What I did:**

1. Installed Node.js on my machine
2. `npx express-generator-typescript --with-auth MyProject`
3. Installed python 3x
4. `pip install nodeenv`
5. `cd C:\MyProjectDir`
6. `nodeenv env`
7. `.env/bin/activate`

Doing the steps above created the `env` folder inside of my main project folder.

**Update:** I see that someone voted to close this question because they thought it was opinion-based. This was not my intention, but I guess I worded it strangely. I am looking for the correct way to install a virtual environment.

**2nd update:** Not sure why this was closed due to not being focused. I'm only asking 1 thing - where does the `nodeenv` folder need to be placed relative to the main project directory? Can someone please explain why they thought the question was unfocused?

Comment: I am not sure why it was closed.  Sometimes it appears people vote that way once they a vote.  I am voting to reopen.